# How to update an image url field in SharePoint list using REST

Tags: jquery, rest, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint list (let's call it 'Employee') and I am using jQuery and REST to read and write properties on that list.

If I want to update e.g. an int property (let's call it 'EmployeeAge'), it's quite straightforward:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: myUrl,
        type: "POST",
        data:  JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.EmployeeListItem' }, 'EmployeeAge': age }),
        headers: { 
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-length": 0,
            "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "IF-MATCH": "*"

        },

        success: successHandlerUpdateEmployeeAge,
        error: errorHandlerUpdateEmployeeAge
        });
```

Now I want to use the same principle to update another column of the list. Let's call it 'EmployeeImage'. The column is of type Hyperlink/Picture and sub type Picture. I want to set the image url attribute of the column for a particular list item.

How do I format the data attribute in my ajax call to support this type of update?

I can find a thousand samples on how to update a title field, but none regarding update of complex types like this.

Comment: Have you tried to send url of the image only? Or you want description as well?

Comment: Yes, of course, and I get a 'Bad request' error back. But actually your comment made me double check, and after inspecting the request with Fiddler, I noticed a more detailed error message I had not seen before: 'The property "EmployeeImage" does not exist on type SP.Data.EmployeeListItem'. This makes me think that the property name is somehow generated out of the url/description structure, so instead of 'EmployeeImage' it should be something like 'EmployeeImage.Url' or similar, but I am not aware of the correct naming.

Comment: I was getting this error when field didn't exist in list at all. But this may not be the case. Try to fill in this column using UI and then return its value using rest to see what format it has.

Comment: You are right, I made a stupid mistake. I had actually renamed the column earlier (for this example, let's say from 'EmpImage' to 'EmployeeImage') and forgotten afterwards, so I tried referencing the column using the title, not the original name. After changing the query to use the correct name, I got another error which seems more relevant: An unexpected 'PrimitiveValue' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'StartObject' node was expected.

Comment: This further strengthens my suspicion that I somehow need to address the column structure in my query. When inspecting the result of a GET request to the same list, I can see the EmployeeImage property in the results, it contains two sub properties, 'Description' and 'Url'. But how do I update them?

Comment: If you check this post (http://spsdev.blogspot.com/2012/11/updating-hyperlink-field-using.html) you can see how it is done using client object model. It could be similar for rest. Try to set the property with javascript object with fields "Url" and "Description".

Comment: I found the answer, but thanks for the tip anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling the error message I got after correcting the column name issue, I found the answer. It actually turned out to be quite simple:

In order to update a complex type like this, you need to provide it as a javascript object, instead of:

```
'EmployeeImage': 'http://myurl'
```

Use this notation to provide the object structure:

```
'EmployeeImage': {Url: 'http://myurl', Description: 'This is the description'}
```

Take a look at this article that pointed me in the right direction: [[http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/a4b4bfcf-1758-4131-9af2-bd1ecf0c839b/not-able-to-insert-a-record-in-a-list-using-rest?forum=appsforsharepoint]](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/a4b4bfcf-1758-4131-9af2-bd1ecf0c839b/not-able-to-insert-a-record-in-a-list-using-rest?forum=appsforsharepoint%5d)