# Post image into list sharepoint with Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, .net-core-2.1

I am working on MS Sharepoint with Microsoft Graph API. I call MS Graph API with .Net Core v2.1.

I want to do a POST request on a Sharepoint List where one of the column is an image column, but I can't find documentations about how to do that... Does anyone know more about how to do it please?

**Update:**

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23194058/how-to-update-an-image-url-field-in-sharepoint-list-using-rest) and I changed my json :

```
{
  "fields": {
    "Title": "Test",
    "Photo": {
      "Url": "https://myurl/picture.jpg",
      "Description":"This is my picture"
    }
  }
}
```

But I have this error message :

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
        "message": "A value without a type name was found and no expected type is available. When the model is specified, each value in the payload must have a type which can be either specified in the payload, explicitly by the caller or implicitly inferred from the parent value.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "34773f4f-131f-4249-8a03-b8a820ba4a6b",
            "date": "2019-05-16T13:26:17"
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that it expects the Photo's value to be a PrimitiveValue and not an object...

Answer (score 0):

May be this should help you.

> POST
>   https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items

Assuming all your images are already uploaded in your site assets folder. Added the below JSON for the image column with site asset image URL id

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "fields": {
    "Title": "Widget",
    "Color": "Purple",
    "Weight": 32,
    "image": "/assets/image5.png" 
  }
}
```

reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-create?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript

Hope it helps